# Updating DB on cache expiration?

Tags: laravel, caching, memcached

I have on my users table a credits field, which decrements by 1 on every user request to the site API. 
Instead of reading / writing to the database on every request I was thinking on using cache.

So on first request I grab credits left, consequent request I decrement by 1 the cache value and then at some point I update db...

So I created a middleware that basically does:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // check api key
        $user = User::where(['api_token' => $request->input('license')])->first();
        if( ! $user )
            return \Response::json(['error' => 'The provided License key is not valid.'], 403);
        // check credits
        $cache_key = 'user_'.$user->id.'_credits';
        $credits = Cache::remember( $cache_key, 1, function ($u) use ($user) {
            return $u->credits;
        });
        $credits::decrement($cache_key);
        //update db on cache expiration ?


        return $next($request);
    }
```

But now I'm not sure when I should update the database with the new cache value or if this it's a good practice at all?

I'm basically trying to work over cache instead over database on every request.

**UPDATE:**
After checking @antonio answer my functions ends like the code below. Problem I see is that $model->credits is not updated until cache expires. But I need it on every call to check if user consumed more credits than they have or to see if I launch auto purchase event.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Create a cache key based on the license
    $cache_key = 'user_'.($license = $request->input('license'));

    // Remember will return a cached user if the license is cached
    $model = Cache::remember($cache_key, 1, function () use ($license) {
        // find the user by the license
        if(! $user = User::where(['api_token' => $license])->first()) {
            // This license does not exists, return a response instead
            return \Response::json(['error' => 'The provided License key is not valid.'], 403);
        }

        // return the user or response
        return $user;
    });

    // If it is a response, break and return it
    if ($model instanceof Response || $model instanceof JsonResponse ) {
        return $model;
    }

    // TODO Validate domain
    //dd($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); or use CORS or embed site_url in request?

    // Decrement the credits
    $model::decrement('credits');

    // Autobuy zone
    if( $model->credits == $model->auto_buy_amount )
        event( new CreditsLimitReached($model) );


    // No more credits
    if( $model->credits < 1 && ! $model->nocredits_email ){
        $model->nocredits_email = true;
        $model->save();
        // TODO clean no credits emails every day
        event( new OutOfCredits($model) );
        return \Response::json(['error' => 'You run out of credits.'], 403);
    }

    // Go to the next middleware
    return $next($request);
}
```

Maybe my question should be how you would code something like this.
Basically I need to perform 3 task on this middleware when a user perform an api call
1- Decrement credits by 1
2- Check if user reached auto purchase zone and fire event 
3- Check if the user run out of credits and fire event once (basically email letting them know that run out of credits)

Answer (score 1):

If you need your data updated in the database, the only thing you can do is to save one request by not looking for your user over and over:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Create a cache key based on the license 
    $cache_key = 'user_'.($license = $request->input('license')).'_credits';

    // Remember will return a cached user if the license is cached 
    $model = Cache::remember($cache_key, 1, function () use ($license) {
        // find the user by the license
        if(! $user = User::where(['api_token' => $license])->first()) {
            // This license does not exists, return a response instead
            return \Response::json(['error' => 'The provided License key is not valid.'], 403);
        }

        // return the user
        return $user;
    });

    // If it is a response, break and return it
    if ($model instanceof Response) {
        return $model;
    }

    // Decrement the credits 
    $model::decrement('credits');

    // Go to the next middleware
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes totally more sense!

Comment: Hi @antonio-carlos-ribeiro unfortunately this don't work as expected. The problem is that while model:decrement('credits') reduces -1 in the database, the $model->credits is not updated until the cache expires